# How can I run Selenium Tests on Android (emulator)?

Tags: android, selenium

At the Selenium wiki [page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Use_instead.) I read that AndroidDriver is removed from the project, and I should use Selandroid instead. However as far as I know Selandroid can be used only to test apks. 
However we want to test a web application.

Is it wort to try the old AndroidDriver, or is it a dead end? What other possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question:
 - As I learned, AndroidDriver is not part of the selenium library any more.
 - Selandroid can be used to test mobile web (not only apk) as well (http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html)